# How to transfer MQFTE files to queue without WebSphere MQ group ID

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I have a WebSphere MQ FTE file to queue transfer in which I am splitting a file to multiple messages using delimiter, when I check messages on queue all messages share same WebSphere MQ group ID. Now my problem is when I try to write those messages back to file, instead of creating multiple files fte create only one file with all messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with WebSphere MQ FTE. When performing a file-to-message transfer, all the messages will have the same group id (as you observe). This is mentioned in the WebSphere MQ FTE Infocenter here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/f2m_simple_split_delim.htm

Then when you perform a message-to-file transfer, the WebSphere MQ FTE agent will use the message group id field on a transfer to ensure it has consumed all the messages for that transfer. So, on the second stage, all of the messages that were created by splitting a single file are written back to a single file.

I think you will need to raise an RFE (Request for Enhancement) on the IBM DeveloperWorks website for IBM to consider if you require this functionality in WebSphere MQ FTe/MFT:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/resource_monitoring.htm

Comment: Thanks for response, I did realize that its not possible with FTE.